# How to click a Span element?

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-ide

for some reason the following xpath will not click when i use the click command in selenium ide.The link iam trying to click is called devices. How can i get this to click?

`xpath=//div[2]/section/nav/div[3]/div/div/span`

Here is the full code:

```
<div title="Devices" class="asm-source-list-group-view">    <header role="heading" aria-hidden="true">Devices</header>    <div><div role="link" aria-selected="true" title="Devices" class="asm-source-list-item-view cw-being-hovered">    <span class="title" aria-hidden="true">Devices</span>    <span class="count cw-hidden" aria-hidden="true">0</span></div><div role="link" aria-selected="false" title="Assignment History" class="asm-source-list-item-view">    <span class="title" aria-hidden="true">Assignment History</span>    <span class="count cw-hidden" aria-hidden="true">0</span></div></div></div>
```

Comment: This code is not complete. Where is the first /div, section, or /nav?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an error that this element is currently not visible or something, You have to implement `WebDriverWait` until the element is visible.

So try this

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class="asm-source-list-group-view"]/header/div[@class="asm-source-list-item-view cw-being-hovered"]/span")));
element.click();
```

When you give an Xpath try to give proper class names as well.

```
Xpath = //div[@class="asm-source-list-group-view"]/header/div[@class="asm-source-list-item-view cw-being-hovered"]/span
```

Answer (score 0):

To click the element you can use the following XPath:

```
//div[@title="Devices"]//div[@title="Devices" and @class="asm-source-list-item-view cw-being-hovered"]//span
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the text Devices is unique,
you can use the `Xpath as //span[contains(text(),'Devices']`
and then use click on this. it should work with `driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Devices']").click();`

Answer (score 0):

Check the Xpath your given her if it's unique if it is and it still want click i suggest you try these 3 ways to click for me one of them always do the job:

```
    Using Actions Lib :

WebElement elemCN = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your path"));
        int widthCN = elemCN.getSize().getWidth();
        act.moveToElement(elemCN).moveByOffset((widthCN / 2) - 2, 0).click().perform();
```

Using JS :

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement SubmitPaiement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your path"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", SubmitPaiement);
```

And finaly the normal `.click()`